# Reduce length of a post on preview page.

Tags: javascript, blogs

I want to make a script that will analyze the length of an individual post, and reduce it to a certain amount of characters on just the home page. How would I do this? Is there a way to do this without using PHP?

Comment: If you're getting the post from a database using PHP, aren't you going to be displaying the post using PHP anyway? You can use javascript to change the amount of characters shown, but what if the client disables javascript? Then the whole thing is shown.

Comment: By a "post" are you really just referring to a string?  Maybe use `.substring()`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with either PHP (which I'd use) or JavaScript.

### PHP

```
$string = 'A very long string ... that is longer than this.';
$string = substr($string, 0, 250); // 250 characters long
```

### JavaScript

For the JavaScript implementation, you would need to have some sort of identifiable container that your text lives in; you could use `<div id="the_post_content"></div>`, for instance.

```
var container = document.getElementById('the_post_content');
var str = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML = str.substring(0, 10); // Container now has text that's truncated
```

**Fiddle of the JS approach [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vFvPB/).**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PHP, then the only thing i can think of is to use JavaScript.

Have a look at http://tpgblog.com/threedots/. This is a jQuery plugin which performs a smart truncation of text and might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you load the page's contents dynamically using `$.load()` or any other AJAX methods, and then put it inside a container that has the css attribute `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/WEgHg/).

the only downside of this approach, that for cross-browser support, it requires `white-space: nowrap;`.